# Erro ao mudar tema do Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, java-ee, maven

Olá, estou aprendendo primefaces e estou tentando mudar o tema do primefaces. Para isso fiz o download por Maven. O tema até aparece nas dependências. Mas aparece a seguinte mensagem quando eu vou executar no navegador:

> Error loading theme, cannot find "theme.css" resource of
>   "primefaces-glass-x" library

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>glass-x</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>           
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>glass-x</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

A estrutura do projeto está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Minha hipótese é de que essas dependências não estão sendo "*deployadas*" no servidor de aplicação. Dependendo da forma de *deploy* (IDE, manual?) isso pode ocorrer. Verifique no diretório do servidor se a nova dependência está corretamente adicionada lá. Como você gera isso? Se for algum script que copia as classes e jars para lá, verifique se está incluindo o novo jar.

Comment: Eu estou usando o Netbeans, e estou usando o "Clean and Build Project", dá tudo certo, sem mensagem de erro. Quando clico na aba Services, Servers, Glassfish e Applications a minha aplicação aparece lá. Verifiquei na pasta dos Dependencies no Windows Explorer e os jar estão lá.

Answer (score 1):

Inclui a pasta `WEB-INF` o tema manualmente. Depois fui em `Tools -> Library` e clique em `Add JAR/Folder` e selecionei o arquivo. Exclui os arquivos .jar do truck `{nome do projeto}/target/{nome do projeto}-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib`. Depois cliquei em `Run and Build Project` e depois `Run` e funcionou.